# How do I prevent text from different table from appearing on a picture html email code

Tags: html, email, debugging, html-email

So I place a picture in first table to position absolute to have text appear above it but the problem I'm having now is the table below text is also appearing on the image. How Do I prevent this from happening ?

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="img/suit1.jpeg" width="590px;" height="500px;" style="position:absolute">
          <h1>each</h1>
          <button>SHOP Now</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<!-- end of row 3 -->
<!-- start of row 4-->
<tr>
  <td>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h1>hello</h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Once you you use absolute positioning, the rest of the elements act as if that element isn't there. Did you try to position the text instead of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try applying `position: absolute` to text elements. In my solution, i've wrapped text inside a div and applied `position: absolute` property. Also, i've applied `position: relative` to the `parent element` of both image and text.

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
      <tr>
        <td style="position:relative;">
          <img src="img/suit1.jpeg" width="590px;" height="500px;">
          <div style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 10px;">
            <h1>each</h1>
            <button>SHOP Now</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<!-- end of row 3 -->
<!-- start of row 4-->
<tr>
  <td>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h1>hello</h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```